# How do I input paramters into a Jenkins perl script from command line?

Tags: perl, jenkins, parameters, csh

## Background

I am running a Jenkns Job, called Job A, that feeds its build parameters into a perl script, called ScriptA.pl, in the following format below:

```
#Check the input params
my $PARAM1 = $ENV{ "PARAM1" };
my $PARAM2 = $ENV{ "PARAM2" };
.....more params fed in the same way
if ( $PARAM1 eq "" ) {
    print "PARAM1 is a required parameter.\n";
    exit 1;
}
if ( $PARAM2 eq "" ) {
    print "PARAM2 is a required parameter.\n";
    exit 1;
}
.....more param checks done in the same way
###Script then runs a bunch of execution statements####
```

## Problem

I am trying to run this script from Linux command line in cshell in the following way to test that the execution component works:

```
/% ScriptA.pl jetFuel steelBeams
```

And it thinks that no parameters have been entered, since this error is returned

```
PARAM1 is a required parameter.
```

## Question

How do I properly input Jenkins parameters into a Jenkins script from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't modify the Perl script so it reads command-line parameters (which would improve its general usability to boot), maybe create a simple wrapper script:

```
#/bin/sh
env PARAM1="$1" PARAM2="$2" perl ScriptA.pl
```

(Yes, `sh`. Nobody should use `csh` for anything in 2019.)

Comment: I know [csh sucks](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html) believe me I have asked this at work as to why we won't use bash as the default.  But I don't have an option in this case since the company default is cshell.